# How to set delete indicator for condition type in PO with user exit?

Tags: abap, purchase-order

There is a condition type let's say ZXXX that includes ZFX1 and ZFX2 conditions.

The scenario wanted is, ZFX1 and ZFX2 conditions must set as deleted when ZXXX exists to prevent duplicate calculation.

It can be handled manually but how it can be possible with user exit? With which user exit?

Thanks, E.

Comment: Just after writing the answer I realized that you ask about PO, not SO. Though the answer will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

No way.

Maybe colleagues correct me but as far as I know there is no way to do it on-the-fly.

**LOEVM_KO** indicator is set:

1. Manually in VK12
2. Via Batch Input

Another probable (at your own risk!) way of setting deletion is FM `RV_KONDITION_SICHERN_V13A` called that way

```
DATA: lt_xkonp TYPE TABLE OF konpdb WITH EMPTY KEY.

APPEND VALUE #( mandt = sy-mandt kopos = '01' kappl = 'V' kschl = 'ZXXX' knumh = '01234567' stfkz = 'A' kpein = '1' loevm_ko = abap_true updkz = 'U') TO lt_xkonp.

CALL FUNCTION 'RV_KONDITION_SICHERN_V13A'
  TABLES db_xkonp = lt_xkonp.
```

However I don't recommend it.

Your general approach is wrong, the deletion indicator is not a setting that can be switched on and off, and under no circumstances it should be done in any user-exit.

This FM contains COMMIT under the hood, so it can break the LUW and corrupt your pricing settings.

Comment: Hello Suncatcher,

Thank you for the response. Maybe I have mentioned it wrong. I don't want to delete but I want to set Deletion Flag. Now I am trying to do it with the ME_PROCESS_PO_CUST with PO Item method. By the help of GET_CONDITIONS & SET_CONDITION. Actually now I can set it but somehow it is setting back again in the SET_CONDITION.

Best regards,

Comment: See my answer, it is impossible to do in runtime, neither in PO nor in SO, and in any exit incl. ME_PROCESS_PO_CUST. Rethink your approach

Comment: Hi Suncatcher, actually I get your point but could not understand why it is not possible. In debug, LOEVM_KO field get "X". But in SET_CONDITIONS it is setting back. Maybe it will be better if I understand because of which parts it is not possible. Thank you.

Comment: Because of [LUW concept](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw70/7.0.31/en-US/41/7af4bfa79e11d1950f0000e82de14a/content.htm?no_cache=true). Del indicator is a static indicator, written in database, when making this change in a user-exit you have to commit to make it work, and making commits in user-exist is [not preferred or even dangerous](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/10/08/partial-code-commit-in-standard-user-exits). Learn more about SAP architecture before constructing such scenarios